# Интрефейс не видит ключевого слова fun

Tags: функции, kotlin, интерфейс

Интрефейс не видит ключевого слова `fun` (выделяет его красным) и подчёркивает красным области без `;`. Классы `fan` видят
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы создали .java файл, а не .kt

Comment: Не интерфейс, а среда разработки не видит и подчеркивает. Не мешало бы уточнять что за она.